# How to fill space between sink and wall?

Tags: sink, plaster, filling

Between my kitchen sink and wall there is a type of plaster that is falling apart.

I'm not sure what material it is, but I would like to remove it all together and put something new.

Could you tell me what it is, or even better what should I fill that space with?

Attached the picture[image]

Comment: It is difficult to know how big the gap is. Could you retake the picture with something there for scale, or edit the question with info on the width of the gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda looks like grout to me, which is the incorrect material.  I would remove all of it, clean the surfaces, applys silicone caulk instead.  Hard to tell the width of the gap from a photo, but you may need some foam backer rod before applying the caulk.

Answer (score 1):

1. In theory up to 30mm You can use silicone. In practice use primer to silicone and  need skill to cover gap wider than 10mm.
2. Can use plaster then silicone on top to make waterproof.
3. Plastic/paper/wood/metal bar mounted to wall with screws/glue and then finished with silicone.
4. There are dedicated solutions like bars with glue/silicone to cover gaps. (do not recomend - used by me are awfull afetr 5-10 years)